# NuGet restore duration exploded and user agent change "buildguest" -> VssAdministrator

Tags: azure-devops

I have a big issue on VSTS

Nuget restore goes from 2min to 6min without specific changes on my branch and the user on vsts changes from "buildguest" to "VssAdministrator".

I really don't know what happened.

Could you help me?

Thanks!!!

Before with buildguest

[image]

After with VssAdministrator
[image]

Comment: What do you mean buildguest and VssAdministrator? Can you add the screen shots for where do they located in your agent?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I have added some screenshots ;-)

Comment: `C:\Users\buildguest` and `C:\Users\VssAdministrator` are the directories of your local machine. And it’s mainly caused by the build definition is changed. I added the details in my answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build was queued by **Hosted agent** (which provided by VSTS server), while in Copy Files task, it copied files from local machine to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`. Since Hosted agent has no permission to access to personal account (such as VssAdministrator account) of a local machine, it will failed copy files.

And the reason why the user changed from buildguest to VssAdministrator is mainly caused by the **build definition is modified** (may be modified by other team members).

To double check if the build definition was changed, you can go to the build definition edit page,in the History Tab, then you can find who, when and how did the build definition changed.

[image]

And you can also add the local files under source control, so you can copy files from `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` without any restrictions.